# LINQ group by then order groups of result

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a table that has the following 3 columns, ID, ShortCode, UploadDate.

I want to use LINQ to group the results by shortcode (and keep all the results) then order those groups and return a list.

I have the following:

```
 rawData.Provider.CreateQuery<PDFDocument>(qb.rootExperession)
.ToList<PDFDocument>().
GroupBy(b=>b.ShortCode)
.SelectMany(b=>b).ToList<PDFDocument>()
```

I want to return all results, grouped by ShortCode, the items within each group sorted by UploadDate and the groups sorted so the one that has the most recent document in it first.

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try

```
rawData.Provider.CreateQuery<PDFDocument>(qb.rootExperession)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.UploadDate)
    .GroupBy(d => d.ShortCode)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```

This should

- Order the items by upload date (descending so newest first)
- Then group them by short code - so within each group the items are still sorted
- The groups are still in descending order, so no need to order again
- Finally concatenate the results into a single list

If performance is an issue you many be better off doing

```
rawData.Provider.CreateQuery<PDFDocument>(qb.rootExperession)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(d => d.ShortCode)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.UploadDate))
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.First().UploadDate)
    .SelectMany(e => e)
    .ToList();
```

which sorts the contents of each group separately rather than sorting everything first and then grouping.

Comment: I was wondering about the order to put the "OrderBy" + "GroupBy" + "OrderBy" and this answers it perfectly

Comment: This is returning me entity of type List, but i want it to be of type group , Compiler error i am getting is
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<xxx>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<long,xxx>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @AnshulNigam You probably want to drop the `SelectMany` line, that is what's flattening out the groups into a single sequence. And the second `ToList`, or at least drop the `<PDFDocument>` type argument. And you'll want to use the first query, not the second.

Comment: What does this look like in expression syntax (the second one)? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In fact, you don't want to group by short code, you want to order by them. So the following query should do the trick:

```
rawData.Provider.CreateQuery<PDFDocument>(qb.rootExperession)
.ToList()
.OrderBy(b => b.ShortCode)
.ThenBy(b => b.UploadDate)
.ToList()
```

**Edit**
If you really want to use a GroupBy, you can do so this way:

```
 rawData.Provider.CreateQuery<PDFDocument>(qb.rootExperession)
.ToList()
.GroupBy(b => b.ShortCode)
.SelectMany(grouping => grouping.OrderBy(b => b.UploadDate))
.ToList()
```

But I discourage it. There is no point creating groups if you do not want groups in the first place!

**Second edit**

I did not get you wanted the groups ordered by UpdateTime too. It complicates a little the query:

```
rawData.Provider.CreateQuery<PDFDocument>(qb.rootExperession)
.ToList()
.GroupBy(b => b.ShortCode)
.Select(grouping => grouping.OrderByDescending(b => b.UploadDate))
.OrderByDescending(grouping => grouping.First().UploadDate)
.SelectMany(grouping => grouping)
.ToList()
```

Comment: Will this order both the elements inside the group by date? And then also order the grouped results?

Comment: All the elements with the first ShortCode will be in the resulting list first, ordered by UpdateTime, then all elements with the second ShortCode, ordered likewise, and so on. The result will be similar to the one you would get in excel when you order your elements primarily by a column, then by another.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your requirements correctly. I thoughts the groups should be ordered by ShortCode and not by the UpdateDate of their newest element. I wil edit with another query responding to this requirement.

Comment: Thank you, this does do what i wanted, but rawlign got in there first